# Capture camera view is not correct in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

i use surface view custom camera using Media Recorder class to record the video , but when the view appear the camera view is some what stretched then original camera , how can i set proper height and width for camera in android using Media Recorder class in surface view custom camera component.

If any one knows the problem means help me out?

Thanks